# Дату из php в datatime mysql

Tags: php, mysql

у меня есть 3 переменные со значение: дня, месяца, года
как мне их засунуть в колонку mysql типа datatime?
заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

datetime - идет в формате `(Y.m.d H:i:s)` поэтому, если у тебя есть, скажем, строка `2011.11.26` просто добавь к ней `00:00:00`, чтоб у тебя переменная была `$date = '2011.11.26 00:00:00';` и тогда засовывай в базу...

Пример...

```
$date = 2011.11.26;
$datesnew = $date." 00:00:00";
$datesnew - можно отправлять в базу...
```